# PHP Wordpress error - Site not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Seem to be having this error when uploading the new theme onto my wordpress website.

The error is as follows.

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home/squatz1/public_html/justserviceofny.com/wp-content/themes/justserviceofny
>   - NEW SITE/front-page.php on line 16

Here is the entire code if this helps.

```
 <?php

/**
 * Home Page template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage JustServiceOfNewYork
 * @since JustServiceOfNewYork 1.0
 */

get_header();

?>

<div class="home-banner" style="background: url('<?= ot_get_option('home-banner'); ?>');
  <?= !empty(ot_get_option('home-banner-height')) ? 'height:' . ot_get_option('home-banner-height') . 'px;' : ''; ?>"
></div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'home' );
    endwhile; // End the loop.
    ?>
  </div><!--.main-content-->

  <?php if ( vct_get_sidebar_class() ) : ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div><!--.content-wrapper-->

<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: You've problem in your if else shorthand.

Comment: You've to `echo` it.

Answer (score 1):

Update code

```
<?php $hb = ot_get_option('home-banner'); ?>
<div class="home-banner" style="background: url('<?= echo $hb; ?>');"
<?= $hbh = ot_get_option('home-banner-height');
echo !empty($hbh) ? 'height:' . $hbh . 'px;' : ''; ?>></div>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you have changed and why it helps solve the problem would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably thats because you are using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on a function return, in following line:

```
!empty(ot_get_option('home-banner-height')) ? 'height:' ....
```

change this line to

```
ot_get_option('home-banner-height') ? 'height:'...
```

just remove the !empty()

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
<div class="home-banner" style="background: url('<?= ot_get_option('home-banner'); ?>');
<?= !empty(ot_get_option('home-banner-height')) ? 'height:' . ot_get_option('home-banner-height') . 'px;' : ''; ?>">
</div>
```

With

```
<div class="home-banner" style="background: url('<?= ot_get_option('home-banner'); ?>');
<?= echo !empty(ot_get_option('home-banner-height')) ? 'height:' . ot_get_option('home-banner-height') . 'px;' : ' '; ?>">
</div>
```

Because, you're echoing the `height`. But as your code it isn't echoing any thing.